# Why does my ListFragment just have a Loading Circle and not display the data I got from remote server?

Tags: android, android-listfragment

I have an application in android that would get data from a remote server and display it on a ListFragment. It is successful in getting the data as it shows on my LogCat but it does not display on the Activity itself where the ListFragment is. It just shows the loading circle and no matter how long I wait it still does the same thing. I am getting the data using httprequest and use an AsyncTask to get them.

Here is the Main Activities codes :

```
package com.thesis.menubook;


import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;


public class MenuMain extends ListActivity {
    JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> categoryList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_menu_main);

        // Populate Category List from database
        new GetCategories().execute();

        //set list on click listener for category
            // on category list click update fragment using dbase query

        // set swipe listener
            // on swipe update fragment using dbase query

        // set add button listener
            // on click add to order list list adapter

        // set order list listener
            // on click remove from list

        // set send button listener
            // update remote database using order list
    }

    class GetCategories extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        /**
         * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
         * */
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
             super.onPreExecute();
             pDialog = new ProgressDialog(MenuMain.this);
             pDialog.setMessage("Loading Categories. Please wait...");
             pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
             pDialog.setCancelable(false);
             pDialog.show();
        }

        /**
         * Getting product details in background thread
         * */
        protected String doInBackground(String... param) {
            Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();
            String ipaddress = b.getString("IPAddress");

            List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            Log.d("IP ADDRESS", ipaddress +" ");

            JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest("http://"+ipaddress+"/MenuBook/selectCategories.php", "GET", params);

            // Check your log cat for JSON reponse
            Log.d("All Categories: ", json.toString() + " ");
            int num = 1;
            try {
                // Checking for SUCCESS TAG
                int success = json.getInt("success");

                if (success == 1) {
                    // products found
                    // Getting Array of Products

                    JSONArray category_list = json.getJSONArray("category_list");

                    // looping through All Products
                    for (int j = 1; j < category_list.length(); j++) {
                        JSONObject c = category_list.getJSONObject(j);

                        // Storing each json item in variable
                        String category = c.getString("category");

                        // creating new HashMap
                        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                        // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                        map.put("category", category);

                        Log.d("category #"+num+"", category + " ");
                        num = num + 1;
                        // adding HashList to ArrayList
                        if(categoryList.contains(map) != true)
                        {
                            categoryList.add(map);
                        }
                        Log.d("Category List", categoryList.toString() + " ");
                    }
                } 
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }

        /**
         * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
         * **/
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            pDialog.dismiss();

            ArrayAdapter<ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>>(MenuMain.this, R.layout.activity_menu_category);
            arrayAdapter.add(categoryList);

            if(arrayAdapter.isEmpty() == true)
            {
                setListAdapter(null);
            }
            else
            {
                setListAdapter(arrayAdapter);
            }
        }

    }



}
```

and here is the ListFragments codes :

```
package com.thesis.menubook;

import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.app.ListFragment;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;

@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
public class MenuCategory extends ListFragment {

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedState);

    }



}
```

This is the ListFragments XML :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ListView 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

</ListView>
```

And if it would help, here is the LogCat :

```
02-13 22:57:35.422: V/TLINE(1349): new: android.text.TextLine@4066c0c0
02-13 22:57:36.702: V/TLINE(1349): new: android.text.TextLine@40674c00
02-13 22:57:59.142: D/dalvikvm(1349): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 161K, 5% free 6481K/6791K, paused 162ms
02-13 22:57:59.184: I/dalvikvm-heap(1349): Grow heap (frag case) to 6.926MB for 513744-byte allocation
02-13 22:57:59.562: D/dalvikvm(1349): GC_CONCURRENT freed 13K, 5% free 6969K/7303K, paused 50ms+26ms
02-13 22:58:02.334: D/NetWork Info(1349): NetworkInfo: type: mobile[UMTS], state: CONNECTED/CONNECTED, reason: simLoaded, extra: internet, roaming: false, failover: false, isAvailable: true
02-13 22:58:08.841: D/Response(1349): org.apache.http.message.BasicHttpResponse@406867f8--response from apache
02-13 22:58:08.841: D/IP Address(1349): 192.168.10.149:80
02-13 22:58:09.181: D/NEXT VALUE --in Async on postexecute(1349): true
02-13 22:58:18.232: D/dalvikvm(1349): GC_CONCURRENT freed 139K, 4% free 7258K/7559K, paused 40ms+13ms
02-13 22:58:18.802: D/URL(1349): http://192.168.10.149:80/MenuBook/checkTable.php
02-13 22:58:23.082: D/Check Table(1349): {"success":1,"tabledb":[{"table_location":"UP","table_seat":"5","table_status":"AVAILABLE","table_ID":"001"}]}
02-13 22:58:23.082: D/Table Status in doinbg(1349): AVAILABLE
02-13 22:58:23.192: D/Table Status in post execute(1349): AVAILABLE
02-13 22:58:25.622: D/IP ADDRESS(1349): 192.168.10.149:80 
02-13 22:58:28.432: D/dalvikvm(1349): GC_CONCURRENT freed 353K, 7% free 7356K/7879K, paused 14ms+264ms
02-13 22:58:32.556: D/All Categories:(1349): {"success":1,"category_list":[{"category":"MAIN DISH"},{"category":"MAIN DISH"},{"category":"DESSERT"}]} 
02-13 22:58:33.273: D/Category List JSON Array(1349): [{"category":"MAIN DISH"},{"category":"MAIN DISH"},{"category":"DESSERT"}]
02-13 22:58:33.852: D/category #1(1349): MAIN DISH 
02-13 22:58:34.982: D/Category List(1349): [{category=MAIN DISH}] 
02-13 22:58:35.164: D/category #2(1349): DESSERT 
02-13 22:58:35.382: D/Category List(1349): [{category=MAIN DISH}, {category=DESSERT}] 
02-13 22:58:35.664: D/Category List(1349): [{category=MAIN DISH}, {category=DESSERT}]
```

Comment: Your list fragment has 0 code in it. What do you expect?

Comment: Oh, I thought it would just be a carrier. How should I populate it?

Comment: You should migrate the code from your ListActivity into your ListFragment. Calling setListShown(true); in the fragment will display the list view instead of the loading circle. Only do that once you're done loading your data, of course. Search for some examples on ListFragments. Tons to help you out

Comment: Any specific function I should implement on the ListFragment to know when it finishes loading data?

Comment: Your onPostExecute should be enough to get you started. You may want to look into using a custom Loader in the future